# How to load folder into "~/" docker-compose, volumes

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, volumes

One of the modules I am using loads a config file from "~/.oci", but my application cannot see it, since I am using docker (with docker-compose). How do I load a volume into the "~/"-directory inside docker?

I have tried this:

```
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app/
      - ./backend/node_modules:/app/node_modules/
      - ~/.oci:~/.oci
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen and what did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default user is `root`, and a standard distribution location for the home directory is `/root` so try

```
- ~/.oci:/root/.oci
```

If your docker container uses a different user, use the `USER` command and hardcode the home path.